# Post request from Vue3 to php doesn't work

Tags: php, post, axios, vuejs3

I having a trouble with axios sending request in vue to php.
When I use post and try to send data to the backend, no data is sent.
what should I do? which part of this code exactly is wrong?
This is my code:

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8888/vueBackend/connection.php',{
     titleName:'Default'
  })
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err=>console.log(err.message))
```

This is response:
[image]

This is my backend code:

```
$server = "localhost";
$dbname = "Vue";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$tblGroup = "Titles";
$dsn = "mysql:host=$server;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
$id = '';
$option = [
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
];
$method = $_Server['REQUEST_METHOD'];
try{
    $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $option);
    if($connection){
        try{
            $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT $tblGroup SET titleName=?");
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$_POST['titleName']);
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Successful";
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
        
    }
}catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo"Error Connect To Database : [ " . $exception->getMessage() . " ] ";

}
```

I expect to send titleName to the backend and php get the titleName value and add it to the database.

Comment: The response might be correct. Check your Request to see if the data is actually sent to the server. Also try adding else-block for your if-statement as the connection might not be created, meaning no error is thrown.

Comment: Are you running it with npm run dev? I am having the problem that I think the php isn't executing when run within a npm dev server

Answer (score 0):

You can try it before to POST variables

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).